Get output probability of a qubit given measurement result of other qubits on Stim
I am doing experiments about Clifford circuits using Stim: a fast stabilizer circuit simulator. For a n-qubit Clifford circuit, I want to get the output probability of q_n given the measurement result of [q_0:q_n-1] (the measurement result of [q_0:q_n-1] can be sampled, as what Stim is doing). Is there any way to do this in Stim? Thanks for answering my question.

Have you tried just sampling the circuit a bunch and measuring it statistically?

Is it able to fix the outcome of [q_0:q_n-1]`` and sample for [q_n]```? If there is a way to do this, will also work of me, thanks

You can postselect using the tableau simulator.
